# How to retrieve deleted Firebase table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I accidentally deleted a table of my firebase real time database. There was a deletion and writing accesibility of public. I immediately closed one of my phone's internet so that it's locale database is not affected. It worked. But how can I browse data and recover it from my android phone with some kind of Sqlite browser?

Comment: Did you finally recover it ?

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris Yeap. I reached out to Firebase support for help and asked for the data to be restored as the olajide said. They helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out first
[Announcing Automated Daily Backups for the Firebase Database](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/announcing-automated-daily-backups-for-the-firebase-database.html)

If you accidentally delete data from your database, you can [reach out to Firebase support for help](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) and ask for the data to be restored.